# Multiclass classification: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

When I use cross-entropy loss function for multiclass text classification, I get the error

```
Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

This is my code:

```
def train(model, iterator):
    
    ...
    for batch in iterator:
        text, text_lengths = batch.Turn
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        predictions = model(text, text_lengths).squeeze(1)
        loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
        acc = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)

       ...
```

Dataset:

```
TEXT = data.Field(tokenize = 'spacy', include_lengths = True)
LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype = torch.long)
```

Forward:

```
 def forward(self, text, text_lengths):
      
        
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
   
        
        packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths)
        
        packed_output, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(packed_embedded)
  

        hidden = self.dropout(torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:], hidden[-1,:,:]), dim = 1))
        output = self.fc1(hidden)
        output = self.dropout(self.fc2(output))
              
            
        return output
```

Comment: Kindly include the shape of your variables and the definition of your model's layers.